# UIToolBar + UITextField = Chat

Tags: ios, objective-c

Have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And try this:

```
- (void)notificationKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {

UIViewAnimationOptions keyboardCurve = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
double keyboardDuration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];
CGFloat pointY = CGRectGetMinY(keyboardRect);

void (^animations)(void) = ^{

    CGRect toolBarRect = self.toolBar.frame;
    toolBarRect.origin.y = pointY - CGRectGetHeight(toolBarRect);
    self.toolBar.frame = toolBarRect;

};

[UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:keyboardCurve
                 animations:animations
                 completion:nil];
}
```

But no animation on my view :(

Some detales:
- in storyboard 1 toolbar with constraints Space to (left,right,button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate frame of a view if you configured this view using auto-layout. Instead you need to expose constraints you need to change (in your case `bottom` I guess) and change value for this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
void (^animations)(void) = ^{

    CGRect toolBarRect = self.toolBar.frame;
    toolBarRect.origin.y = pointY - CGRectGetHeight(toolBarRect);

    for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.view.constraints) {
        if(constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom && constraint.secondItem == self.toolBar) {
            constraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - pointY;
        }
    }

    self.toolBar.frame = toolBarRect;
    [self.toolBar layoutIfNeeded];

};
```

Thank sha for help